# A simpler data structure for key-value lookup?

Tags: c#, performance, memory, dictionary, lookup

For a small set of key/value pairs (default 2, max 5), a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` seems like overkill. Is there a much simpler data structure that could be used in my case ? I'm caching computed values for certain objects (i.e. `<MyClass, double>`), so retrieval speed is important.

Thanks

Comment: If retrieval speed is important, the O(1) performance of `Dictionary<Tkey, TValue>` seems ideal, no?  Why does this data structure seem like overkill to you?

Comment: @Robert: It's *possible* that the OP has actually benchmarked `Dictionary<,>` and found it too slow. O(1) only says how fast the lookup time grows with size - it says nothing about the constant factors. This *may* be a reasonable question, but we haven't heard enough about measurements already taken.

Comment: Here's a great article on performance of different collection types.  Notice the size of the collection can have a big impact on which one is best for you.  http://blog.bodurov.com/Performance-SortedList-SortedDictionary-Dictionary-Hashtable/

Comment: @DavidJBerman: But all those graphs start at 50 items, which is *way* more than the OP is interested in. This is a very niche situation. I still suspect the OP would be fine with just `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` (created with an appropriate capacity) would probably work just as well in this case... but it wouldn't be terribly idiomatic. (Just to be clear, you'd simply call `Equals` on each key element, ignoring the hash code completely.) If `List<T>` feels a bit heavy to you, you could even go down to `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[]` if you wanted. Ick, but hey... it's your code.

Have you actually tried `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` and found it to be too slow? "Seems like overkill" doesn't seem nearly as good an argument as "I've tried it, profiled it, and found an unacceptable amount of my application's time is spent creating dictionaries and looking up entries in them. I need my application to have performance characteristic X and at the moment I only have Y."

If your key type has a particular ordering (and if you were going to perform more lookups on the data structure than you were going to create instances) you could sort the list, meaning you would have a maximum of 3 comparisons for any particular lookup. With only 5 entries you could even hard-code all the potential paths, if you were looking to optimize to the hilt. (You might even have different implementations for 2, 3, 4 and 5 elements. It's getting a little silly at that point though.) This is basically a `SortedList<TKey, TValue>` implementation, but you *may* be able to optimize it a little for your scenario of only having a few entries. Again, it's worth trying the built-in types first.

What's vital is that you know how important this part of your code really is to your overall performance - and when it will be "good enough" so you can stop appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

If the set of keys is known at compile time, than you could simply create a class (or struct) with nullable properties that hold the values.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an array like `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[]`, you could sort it and then search using a binary search. But this is only fast if you have to sort once and then retrieve many times.

Answer (score -2):

I often like to use the Hashtable class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx).

Another thing you can do though, is not worry about managing any cache yourself and just use the caching from ASP.NET. All you have to do is include the system.web assembly and then you can use it even in non-web applications.  Here's an article on using the .Net cache code in a Windows Forms app.  It's really simple.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/cacheinwinformapps.aspx

D.

Comment: You really shouldn't be using the non-generic classes unless you have to these days. Why throw away type safety? Additionally, in this case `TValue` is a double, so you'd be incurring an unboxing penalty on each lookup pointlessly. There's also *no* indication from the question that the OP is doing *anything* with ASP.NET.

Comment: Hi Jon, if you read my answer fully before placing this comment, you'd see that my response explains how you can use the Caching class that you would use in an ASP.NET app with non-asp.net apps.  Also, you don't have to lose type safety, when you get your object out of the Hashtable you can use the "as" operator (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx).  When caching data, being able to put different types of objects in your cache is an ADVANTAGE!

Comment: `as` operator is not for value types. And regardless of your ability to cast when you get it out, you still box and unbox.

Comment: @DavidJBerman: But the OP doesn't *want* different types of data. He wants a specific key type and a specific value type. And while Hashtable doesn't lose *execution-time* type safety, it loses *compile-time* type safety. You should really, really embrace generics where possible. It's true that I didn't read the link before - but I still don't see what benefit the ASP.NET cache would have in this situation. There's simply no call for it.